# SignalR javascript console log redirect

Tags: javascript, signalr

SignalR logs lots of nice stuff to the console log when hubConnection.logging is turned on, but I would like it to go to a remote log instead. I can't see any way to redirect that output to my log besides replacing console.log which I really don't want to do.

Anyone know how?

Comment: Just as an FYI, for ASP.NET Core SignalR, this is covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics#javascript-client-logging), under *JavaScript client logging*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `$.connection.fn.log` which is called for all logging in the JS client:

```
$.connection.fn.log = function(msg) {
   // pipe somewhere else..
}
```

Note that this log method always gets called, i.e. if you want it to respect the `$.connection.hub.logging` setting, you have to check for that explicitly.